# How do I handle a get reqest to an offline source in Angular2?

Tags: rest, angular, http-get

I have the following problem:  I have a Angular 2 application which sends a get request like this:

```
getStatus(cb:(boolean, error) => void){
    this.http.get(this.uri+'/forms/status')
    .subscribe(
        (res: Response) =>{
            console.dir(res);
            this.response = res;
            if(res.status === 200)cb(true, null);
            else cb(false, "No connection established");
        }
    )
}
```

So this method should check,if my service is online or not and should send a message to the user, if it is offline. My problem is that I always will get

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
when I call the method. 
My question is how I can handle it that the method just returns the boolean as false, when my service is offline.

Best regards.

Switching to

```
getStatus(cb:(boolean, error) => void){
this.http.get(this.uri+'/forms/status')
.map(val => true)
.catch(err => Observable.of([false])
.subscribe(
    (res: boolean) => cb(res, res ? null : "No connection established");)
}
```

returns the error message:

```
ERROR in [default] C:\Development\Code\formcreator-ui\app\src\service\form.servi
ce.ts:66:8
Argument of type '(res: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type
 'NextObserver<boolean[]> | ErrorObserver<boolean[]> | CompletionObserver<boolea
n[]> | ((value: boo...'.
  Type '(res: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: boolean[]) =>
 void'.
    Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to suppress the error message in the browser console, then you're out of luck. This error is created by the browser and there is no way avoiding it.

Otherwise this should do what you want.

```
getStatus(cb:(boolean, error) => void){
    this.http.get(this.uri+'/forms/status')
    .map(val => true)
    .catch(err => Observable.of([false])
    .subscribe(
        (res: Response) => cb(res, res ? null : "No connection established");
    )
}
```

but instead of `cb` I would do it like

```
getStatus(){
    return this.http.get(this.uri+'/forms/status')
    .map(val => true);
    .catch(err => Observable.of([false])
}
```

then it can be used like

```
this.getStatus().subscribe(avail => avail ? doSomething() : console.log("No connection"));
```

Observables are to avoid callback hell, therefore using this feature is preferred instead of passing callbacks around.

Comment: When I try this, it fails at map(true) with "Argumebnt of type boolean is not assignable to parameter of type(value:boolean[], index: number)"

Comment: Can you please try `Observable.of(false)`? I don't use TS myself and not entirely sure about all details.

Comment: Doesn't work either. It works with mapTo(true), but then I can't subscribe to it.

Comment: Stupid. `map` should be `.map((val) => true)` and `catch` and map need to be switched.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, it's a completly new world for me. it seems that subscribe expects a NextObserver<boolean> :/

Comment: I tried to reproduce in Plunker but it refused to make HTTP calls at all there :-/ As mentioned. I don't use it actively myself. `.subscribe()` works on any observable. How does your current code look like exactly? Can you please edit your question and add it there?

Comment: Well, the error message gets thrown by Visual studio code and npm run dev , when I copy and paste this method.

Comment: ERROR in [default] C:\Development\Code\formcreator-ui\app\src\service\form.servi
ce.ts:66:8
Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of typ
e 'NextObserver<boolean[]> | ErrorObserver<boolean[]> | CompletionObserver<boole
an[]> | ((value: boo...'.
  Type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: boolean[]) =
> void'.
    Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
        Property 'type' is missing in type 'boolean[]'.

Comment: That's probably `(res: Response)`. Change it to `(res: boolean)`. Can you please add your current code to the question, otherwise I don't know how to map the error message to the code.

Comment: And what happens when you use `Observable.of(false)` as mentioned above?

Comment: Then Observable of doesn't work. But I think I will go on with something else and come back later to that problem.

Comment: What does "Then Observable doesn't work" mean exactly?